# Does Nlog support .NET Framework 3.5?

Tags: .net-3.5, nlog

Does Nlog support .NET 3.5 framework? If yes, please suggest which version of Nlog can be used? I am unable to get from NuGet library from Visual Studio.

Comment: "I am unable to get from NuGet library from Visual studio." - we can't help on that without any details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,  .NET 3.5 is supported, also for the latest release, NLog 4.4.12. The latest release is recommended.

> NLog supports the following platforms:
>   .NET Framework 3.5, 4, 4.5, 4.6 & 4.7

Source: http://nlog-project.org